# Binding extension that delays change if source is null

Tags: wpf, data-binding

TL;DR: How could one write a (one-way) binding extension that works just like a normal binding but delays if the source is set to `null`?

---

I am using an MVU architecture (using [Elmish.WPF](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF)) and trying to keep invalid states out of the model. This means that if my app should not show a certain dialog, the state for that dialog should not exist in the model at all. I am then using bindings to set the `Visibility` of the XAML UserControl representing the dialog to Collapsed if its `DataContext` is `null`.

Unfortunately, this doesn't play well with animations. The dialog is automatically animated in and out when toggling its `Visibility`. But since the only way the `Visibility` can be false is for the dialog's model (`DataContext`) to be `null`, this means that the visual behavior is that every input in the dialog is immediately emptied once the animation starts, causing resizing and generally looking weird.

I'm not experienced with WPF, but AFAIK a possible solution to this would be to use a custom binding extension (which may be limited to be one-way if necessary) that delays the change to `null` until the animation has completed. This means that when the part of the model representing the dialog is removed from the app's model and the dialog's `DataContext` is set to null, nothing would immediately change as far as the XAML controls are concerned, except for the `Visibility` binding which would of course use a standard binding to the same property that the `DataContext` is bound to (not directly to the `DataContext` itself).

Unfortunately, custom markup extensions seem rather arcane to me, so I don't even know where to start. Is this possible, and how could it be done?

I can also accept other answers that solve the underlying problem.

(I know that a workaround is to simply not remove the dialog state from the model when the dialog is closed, or add some kind of delay before removing it in order to allow the animation to complete, but the former does not allow me to keep invalid states out of the model, and the latter imposes unnecessary UI-related animation concerns on the central logic, which may be used across different UI projects.)